# How to add a VEGA graph into streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit, vega

I'm new on Streamlit and I would like to use VEGA (not vega lite) to plot networks in a Streamlit app.
Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit doesn't support adding Vega charts directly. At the moment, we don't have plans to implement support for Vega, due to a lack of interest from the community, but feel free to add your perspective [here](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/945) if it's something you'd like to see prioritized.